# Libgdx Draw multiple random spites from an array at different positions

Tags: java, libgdx

I recently found out how to draw a random sprite and I wonder if I could draw multiple sprites that are completely chosen at random from my array (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array) at different positions and my sprites can't repeat each other (can't have more than one of the same card).

The card class

```
public class Spades extends CardTypes {

    public Array<Sprite> spades = new Array<Sprite>(5);

    public void cards() {
        spades.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/AS.png")));
        spades.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/2S.png")));
        spades.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/3S.png")));
        spades.add(four = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/4S.png")));
        spades.add(five = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/5S.png")));
    }
}
```

The render method

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    Sprite card;
    private Spades spading = new Spades();

    private Main game;

    //create method
    public GameScreen(Main game) {
        this.game = game;
        spading.cards();
        card = spading.spades.random();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        game.getBatch().begin();
        game.getBatch().draw(card,100,0);
        game.getBatch().end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a loop with some Math.random values to grab a random card from your array. To ensure no card can be drawn twice you could use another array to store all previously chosen cards and for each new card first check if it isn't in that array.

For example:

```
Array<Sprite> drawnCards = new Array<Sprite>();
int randomCardNr = (int) Math.random() * 52;

for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCardsToBeDrawn; i++) {
    if (!drawnCards.contains(yourCardArray.get(randomCardNr)) { // Check if it hasn't been drawn before

        drawCard(yourCardArray.get(randomCardNr)); // This is your method to draw a card
        drawnCards.add(yourCardArray.get(randomCardNr)); // Add to drawnCards array
    }
}
```

Go wild with the random numbers to draw from different arrays if you want to.

Comment: Just small fix is needed here - if random card is picked before number of drawn card will be less, so this "i++" from for loop shouldn't be there but inside loop body and should happen only if card is not doubled. Also "amountOfCardsToBeDrawn must be less than 52 or you may end up in endless loop.

Comment: True, this is only an example, one could add if statements to avoid those cases. That depends on the users needs.

Comment: How do I create a loop to generate a new random number every time?

Comment: You're right, this loop will try to draw the same card each round, you should add an extra line inside the loop before the if statement: `randomCardNr = (int) Mant.random() * (yourCardArray.size() - drawnCards.size());`

Comment: Also for the drawCard() method what should be in it?

Comment: For example `game.getBatch().draw(card,100,0);` , and then you'll have to put the for loop between the batch begin and batch end lines.

Comment: I think you should follow some more java tutorials about loops and methods. Then you'll understand what exactly you're doing here.

Answer (score 2):

I have no ready-to-paste code sample for you, instead I can give you some hints to think about:

- `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array` has a `shuffle` method
- You have sprites, so use them to store the card's postion: `ace.setPosition(0, 100)`
- You have sprites, so use them for drawing: `ace.draw(game.getBatch())`

Using these methods you should be able to draw random cards in a way that they don't change their position in every `render` call.

Further reading:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites